# How does Google identify devices?

Tags: security, device, tracking, google-account

I am using my google account to log in to the same computer on 2 different browsers, and when checking the Security => Your device => Device management => Details, google tells me I'm Use 1 device to login to Google account. How does Google determine I'm using 1 device?

[image: This Image]

Comment: Hey! Do you mean, how does google know, both browsers are on the same device? Well for example by the IP-address. But also through properties of your operating system. They track everythin they can. But anyway I would say your tags (javascript, asp.net-core) are totally wrong here. Maybe you change the tags to proper target the experts

Answer (score 2):

https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/

Take a look at the browser fingerprint that can be generated using for example:

- HASH OF CANVAS FINGERPRINT https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API
- AUDIOCONTEXT FINGERPRINT https://audiofingerprint.openwpm.com/
- HASH OF WEBGL FINGERPRINT
- WEBGL VENDOR & RENDERER

All these traces identify the hardware rather than the browser

Comment: I am shocked. Does it mean they can detect my device in a browser context? I do not mean the usual information like the OS send as an useragent. I just logged in a private tab and they told me when I logged in that I am using a DELL laptop. How?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a request is made from a device,

Device automatically sends **user-agent** in header

This user-agent tells you which device you are using

For eg: [https://www.deviceinfo.me](https://www.deviceinfo.me/)
Visit this from different browser ,it will detect both OS and browser(even browser version)

Visit the same link from mobile phone

or you on go in inspect(Ctrl+shift+i) tool of browser

1. Look for 'responsive' on top middle,
2. change it to iphone or ipad
3. visit the link again